# How to catch child_process restarting/forking itself

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get a node script to run another command with `child_process`, which starts up a server, but this server has 'live reload' functionality.

As far as I understand, as soon as anything changes, the child process restarts, and my parent process continues as if the child died/exited.

I want my parent process to re-connect to a newly forked/spawned child.

Is there any way to do this?

```
const command = 'server --listen 7070';
const process = child_process.exec(command);
process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
process.on('exit', (event) => {
  console.log('The child process exited')
});
```

In this example, the server keeps running, but the `stdout` processing stops after the child process restarts itself for the first time.

Comment: You can have the child communicate with the parent before it restarts itself and the parent can then look for that process.  Or, as soon as the child exits, you can poll for a short time (however long it might take for the new child to start) looking at the process list for the new child.  It isn't clear what "reconnect" to the new child means.

Comment: In this context, I want to keep seeing the `stdout` output of the newly spawned child process.

Comment: I wouldn't think there's any way to do that because that original stdio stream is gone when the child is gone.  The new child could connect itself back to the parent with whatever your favorite IPC tool is.  Or the parent could watch for a new child and connect to it.  Both sides would have to cooperate in the reconnect to the new child.